# Apex Debug is not showing the errors correctly

Tags: apex, before-trigger, debug-logs

I have trigger on Task Object as below.

```
trigger TaskTrigger1 on Task (before insert, before update,after insert) {
If (Trigger.isBefore) {
    If (Trigger.isInsert) {  
    // TaskQueue is Group of Queue Type
    Id taskQueue = [select id from Group where DeveloperName = 'TaskQueue'].Id;
    System.debug('taskQueue'+taskQueue);
    for (Task taskRec : Trigger.new) {
            taskRec.OwnerID = taskQueue;
            System.debug('taskRec'+taskRec);
        }
    }
    If (Trigger.isUpdate) {
        
    }            
}
If (Trigger.isAfter) {
    If (Trigger.isInsert) {
        
    }
}}
```

I have kept the version of Trigger as 35.0. Whenever I go ahead and create a task I am getting an error, as below

"TaskTrigger1: data changed by trigger for field Assigned To ID: id value of incorrect type: 00GB0000004PHOWMA4" which I am aware of because of the version issue ( Assign To ID supports from V48.0).

Ref: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001SodzQAC&title=assign-tasks-to-a-queue-function-is-not-working-if-a-task-entity-is-cached-with-version-48

The question is this information is nowhere captured in the debug logs. I kept the debug level to the finest. Any possible reason?

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Are you asking why your error message doesn't match the Known Issue error?  Why can't you just update your API versions and resolve your issue?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @DavidCheng . I can make it work by changing the API to anything above 48. The ask here is I see the error only on UI, not on the debug logs. Why the error wasn't captured in the debug log.